# ant filterset property scope

Tags: ant

I'd like to use a filterset to write out a file replacing a variable which is set as an ant property. I can pass the property if I have a nested filterset, but not a refid; I'm reusing the filterset, so I'd like to use the refid.

foo.old just contains `foo=@foo@`

This works:

```
<target name="filterset-test1">
  <property name="bar" value="here is foo" />
  <copy file="foo.old" tofile="foo.new1">
    <filterset  begintoken="@" endtoken="@">
      <filter token="foo" value="${bar}" />
    </filterset>
  </copy>
</target>
```

And this fails to replace the token:

```
<filterset id="test-filters" begintoken="@" endtoken="@">
  <filter token="foo" value="${bar}" />
</filterset>
<target name="filterset-test3">
  <property name="bar" value="property doesn't pass thru" />
  <copy file="foo.old" tofile="foo.new3">
    <filterset refid="test-filters" />
  </copy>
</target>
```

Is there a way to do the latter? I've also tried writing a properties file and using it as the `filtersfile` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears to be that inside the top-level filterset:

```
<filterset id="test-filters" begintoken="@" endtoken="@">
  <filter token="foo" value="${bar}" />
</filterset>
```

The property `bar` is undefined. Moving the property definition for `bar` outside target `filterset-test3` should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="filter-test">

  <property name="bar" value="property doesn't pass thru" />

  <filterset id="test-filters" begintoken="@" endtoken="@">
    <filter token="foo" value="${bar}" />
  </filterset>

  <target name="filterset-test3">
    <copy file="foo.old" tofile="foo.new3">
      <filterset refid="test-filters" />
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, cpeisert. What I need to do is set the information inside filterset-test3 or even a different target that filterset-test3 is dependent upon, however. Is this possible, or do I need to reexamine my order of operations?

Comment: To make the your filter logic more modular, one approach would be to wrap the <copy> task inside a macrodef. Then you could nest the <filter> task inside <copy> like your first example without using `refid`.

Comment: I took your advice and just rescoped the properties. Thanks!